# Docker Swarm on Azure: Correct use of docker4x/logger-azure

Tags: azure, logging, docker, docker-swarm

I'm using the [predefined build of Docker on Azure](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/) (Edge Channel) and one of the features is the logging feature. Checking with `docker ps` on the manager node I saw there is this `editions_logger` container ([docker4x/logger-azure](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker4x/logger-azure/)), which catches all the container logs and writes them to an Azure storage account.

How do I use this container directly to get the logs of my containers?

1. My first approach was to find the right storage and share and download the logs directly from the Azure portal.
2. The second approach was to connect to the container directly using `docker exec -ti editions_logger cat /logmnt/xxx.log`
3. Running `docker service logs xxx` throws `only supported with experimental daemon`

All approaches (not the third one though) seem quite over complicated. Is there a better way?

Comment: An alternative to "logger-azure" is to use Azure OMS directly.  The following command will work: `docker service create  --name omsagent --mode global  --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,destination=/var/run/docker.sock  -e WSID="<WSID>" -e KEY="<PRIMARYKEY>" -p 25225:25225 -p 25224:25224/udp  --restart-condition=on-failure microsoft/oms`.  For more information on OMS, visit the following link replacing the "DCOS" related information with the above command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-kubernetes-oms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, we can use `--volumes` to store container logs to Host, then use **Logstash** to collect logs from the volumes.

In the host machine to open a fixed directory D, and mount the logs to the sub-directory of the D directory, then the mount D to Logstash. In this way, the Logstash container can collect all logs from other containers.
It works like this:
[image]

Comment: Another way, as Howe said, we can use OMS to collect the container logs.Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks! I will check out both approaches this week and I will keep you updated, but the the logger-azure containers itself does not provide any tools to inspect the logs more easily? The setup for Azure seems very well planned though, so this make me wondering that this important aspect is covered so impractical (or requires additional tools to use it effectively). Thanks!

Comment: You are right, it is better to have a simple way to view the logs of containers, but for now, I have not find any information about this in official documentation, maybe this feature will add in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I checked both approaches on our cluster, but we found a fairly easy way to check the logs for now. The Azure OMS approach is really good and i can recommend it, but the setup is too huge for us at the moment. Also the logstash approach is good.

Luckily the tail command supports wildcards and using this we can view our logs nicely.

```
docker exec -ti editions_logger bash
cd /logmnt 
tail -f service_name*
```

Thank you very much for the different approaches! Im looking forward to the new Swarm features (there is already the `docker service logs` command, so in the future it should be even easier to check the logs.)